# ReCAPTCHA not working when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I was getting spam emails from my contact form so I added googles ReCAPTCHA to my contact form. After lots of tries and fails, I am at a point of asking for help.

First, my HTML is in a reveal and calls the ajaxsubmit.php

```
            <div class="reveal" id="contactModal" data-reveal>
          <h1>Contact Us</h1>
          <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
            <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="/assets/js/ajaxsubmit.php" class="large-12 cell">
              <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                <div class="large-6 cell">
                  <label>Name*</label>
                  <input id="name" name="name" required type="text" placeholder="Name..." /> </div>
                <div class="large-6 cell">
                  <label>Company*</label>
                  <input id="company" type="text" placeholder="Company..." name="company" required/> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                <div class="large-6 cell">
                  <label>Email*</label>
                  <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..." name="email" required /> </div>
                <div class="large-6 cell">
                  <label>Phone*</label>
                  <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Phone..." name="phone" required/> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                <div class="large-12 cell">
                  <label>Message*</label>
                  <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message..." name="message" required></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                  <div class="large-6 cell">
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MYSITEKEY"></div>
                  </div>
                <div class="large-6 clear-fix">
                  <button class="button float-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div id="form-messages"></div>
          </div>
          <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
        </div>
```

After the user completes the form and the recaptcha my ajax.js file grabs it when they click submit and prevents default action.

```
$(function() {
var form = $("#ajax-contact");
var formMessages = $("#form-messages");
//We set our own custom submit function
$(form).submit(function(event) {
//Prevent the default behavior of a form
event.preventDefault();
//Get the values from the form
var name = $("#name").val();
var company = $("#company").val();
var phone = $("#phone").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
//AJAX POST
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/assets/js/ajaxsubmit.php",
data: {
name: name,
company: company,
email: email,
phone: phone,
message: message,
captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()}
}).done(function(response) {
$(formMessages).removeClass("error");
$(formMessages).addClass("success");
// Set the message text.
$(formMessages).text(response);
// Clear the form.
$("#name").val("");
$("#company").val("");
$("#phone").val("");
$("#email").val("");
$("#message").val("");
}).fail(function(data) {
// Make sure that the formMessages div has the "error" class.
$(formMessages).removeClass("success");
$(formMessages).addClass("error");
// Set the message text.
if (data.responseText !== "") {
    $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
} else {
    $(formMessages).text("Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.");
}
});
});
});
```

After the Ajax.js it gets posted VIA the Ajax jquery function $.ajax to my ajaxsubmit.php file.

```
 <?php
// If the form was submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

// If the Google Recaptcha box was clicked
if(isset($_POST[‘captcha’]) && !empty($_POST[‘captcha’])){    
$captcha=$_POST[‘captcha’];
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=MYSECRET&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’]);
$obj = json_decode($response);

// If the Google Recaptcha check was successful
if($obj->success == true) {
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
$name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
$company = strip_tags(trim($_POST["company"]));
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$phone = strip_tags(trim($_POST["phone"]));
$message = trim($_POST["message"]);
// Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($company) OR empty($phone) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
http_response_code(400);
echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
exit;
}
        // Set the recipient email address.
        $recipient = "EMAIL";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Company: $company\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Phone: $phone\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
http_response_code(200);
echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
}

else {
http_response_code(500);
echo "Oops! Something went wrong, and we couldn’t send your message.";
}

}

// If the Google Recaptcha check was not successful
else {
echo "Robot verification failed. Please try again.";
}

}

// If the Google Recaptcha box was not clicked
else {
echo "Please click the reCAPTCHA box.";
}

}

// If the form was not submitted
// Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
else {
http_response_code(403);
echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
?>
```

Now this is where my issue lies it never gets past the very first if statement `if(isset($_POST[‘captcha’]) && !empty($_POST[‘captcha’]))` and goes straight to Please click the ReCAPTCHA box.   If I Echo the captcha var it has data in it. So I don't understand why it won't continue into the first if statement any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: you can use this for validate if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0){
   console.log("The captcha has been already solved");
}

Comment: More clarification getting this error from error reporting <br /> <b>Warning</b>: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in <b>/assets/js/ajaxsubmit.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=...;respons...): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in <b>/assets/js/ajaxsubmit.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br /> <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/assets/js/ajaxsubmit.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is $_POST['captcha']

From the google dev site

```
g-recaptcha-response POST parameter when the user submits the form on your site
grecaptcha.getResponse(opt_widget_id) after the user completes the reCAPTCHA challenge
As a string argument to your callback function if data-callback is specified in either 
the g-recaptcha tag attribute or the callback parameter in the grecaptcha.render method
```

on the recaptcha website you find details on how to validate the recaptcha itself:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#site/319444416